# SQL convert XML with same nodes to dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a XML column with same names for the nodes.

This is how the XML column looks like. It has three `Mapping` nodes.

```
<Mappings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Mapping>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>John</Name>
  </Mapping>
  <Mapping>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>Jill</Name>
  </Mapping>
  <Mapping>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Name>Jason</Name>
  </Mapping>
</Mappings>
```

Expected Result set

```
   ID          Name
------------------------
   1           John
   2           Jill
   3           Jason
```

This is what I have tried doing

```
select
    convert(varchar(50), ID.query('./text()')) as ID,
    convert(varchar(50), fName.query('./text()')) as [Name]
from [MyTable]
cross apply XMLCol.nodes('/Mappings/Mapping/ID') as map1(ID)
cross apply XMLCol.nodes('/Mappings/Mapping/Name') as map2(fName)
```

This repeat the ID 3 times with all 3 names.

I only want to repeat the ID once with the respective name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close.  Try

**Example**

```
Select ID     = xAttr.value('ID[1]', 'int')
      ,[Name] = xAttr.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(100)')
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply XMLCol.nodes('/Mappings/Mapping') B(xAttr)
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Name
1   John
2   Jill
3   Jason
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you have two slashes at the beginning of Mappings XMLCol.nodes('//Mappings/Mapping')? I tested with a single slash and it worked just fine. Just wondering if its a typo or you had a reason behind it. Thanks

Comment: @nmess88 No reason.  1 slash would work as well.   Just a lazy copy/paste

Comment: even a single slash at the beginning is not required in this case.

Comment: And to add to this: A `//` triggers the *deep search*. It will find `<Mappings>` **anywhere in the XML**. In larger structures this can cost a lot and might return unexpected results... And just to mention this: `(ID/Text())[1]` performs better than `ID[1]`. Anyway, +1 from my side ;-)

Comment: @AlexKudryashev About *no slash required*: Using the *single slash* tells the engine "Start from the root node!". No slash tells the engine "This is a relative path. Follow it from the current node!". In this case the effect is the same, but it is good to know the differences ;-)